# Which has better performance HMAC SHA-2 or KMAC SHA-3

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, sha, hmac

I am attempting to implement either HMAC SHA-2 or KMAC SHA-3 on a Raspberry Pi 3 (and possibly a Raspberry Pi 0). Which would have better performance? Any suggestions are very helpful.

Comment: Why not test it?

Comment: Why would you need to implement HMAC SHA-2? That's quite a common algorithm and Raspberries are still general purpose CPU's for which plenty of software will be available. Raspberry Pi 3 has a 64 bit CPU which would make SHA-512 relatively fast - if you install a 64 bit OS anyway.

Comment: The performance depends on your implementation. There are many different implementations possible of the same algorithm which result in wildly different execution times and side-channel behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to implement either HMAC SHA-2 or KMAC SHA-3 on a Raspberry Pi 3 (and possibly a Raspberry Pi 0). Which would have better performance?

RPI-3's are AMRv8. ARMv8 has CRC and optionally Crypto extensions. The Crypto extensions include Carryless Multiplies, AES, SHA-1 and SHA-2 acceleration. Since there is potentially acceleration for SHA-2 but not SHA-3, SHA-2 will be faster on devices with the crypto extensions.

You can find the source code for SHA using ARMv8 intrinsics at [GitHub | SHA-Intrinsics](https://github.com/noloader/SHA-Intrinsics).

If there is no hardware acceleration, then you need to find an implementation that provides the best cycles-per-byte throughput. That's your job to find.